# Android studio SQLite primary key not returned

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

i have a table named student using SQLite, i'm trying to get the id of one student using a SELECT query, there is my method :

```
 public int getID(String name, String surname){
    int id;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT* FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_2 + " =\"" + name + "\" AND " + COL_3 + " =\"" + surname + "\";";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null); //App is crashing here
    id = cursor.getInt(0);
    return id;
}
```

My code for insert data into the database :

```
 public boolean insertStudent(String name, String surname){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3, surname);
    long result=db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

And then Create query table :

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    //Requête SQL de la création de la table student
    db.execSQL("CREATE table " + TABLE_NAME + "(student_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, surname TEXT)");
```

The app is crashing on db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null);, i don't know why.
I tried  to insert manually the id, with an integer autoincremented, not working, so, i don't know, waiting for you to help me, thanks

Comment: Because i need the Id for an other table which have student_id as foreign key

Comment: I'm using a spinner, it display the name and the surname of a student, i know it's not the optimal method, but i don't know how to get the id without my conditions, beause the user will add a student manually by filling the name and the surname field, and he can add mark, and then he can consult all his students (with their mark which is my other table) this is all my app is doing for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in SQL go in `'single quotes'`. The `"double quoted strings"` are taken as identifiers and you get a syntax error about them since there are no columns by those names.

To avoid the need for quoting and avoid SQL injection, it's better to supply SQL arguments as variables like:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT* FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_2 + " =? AND " + COL_3 + " =?;";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { name, surname });
```

After fixing this issue you'll crash with the invalid cursor position issue highlighted by MikeT.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suspect that the crash is actually on the next line as you are trying to extract data from a position that is before the first row.

I'd suggest trying :-

```
public int getID(String name, String surname){
    int id = -1;
    String selectQuery = "SELECT* FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + COL_2 + " =\"" + name + "\" AND " + COL_3 + " =\"" + surname + "\";";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery,null); //App is crashing here
    if (cursor.moveToFirst) {
        id = cursor.getInt(0);
    }
    return id;
}
```

That is, if the Cursor is not empty then you will move to the first row and extract the data from an actual row. If the Cursor is empty, then -1 will be returned.

Comment: -1 is returned, so it mean that my primary key is not generated and is null, is it normal ? Thanks for the anser by the way !

Comment: it's working, in my query, i put ";" so that was why it wasn't working, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with crash? An stacktrace would be helpful.

Anyhow, additionally to what was mentioned by others there is a typo in your SQL:

```
"SELECT* FROM "
```

I assume you need a space before *:

```
"SELECT * FROM "
```

Comment: not really: my `sqlite3` accepts even thing like `"SELECT*FROM table_name ..."` - of course you are right it is not good form of writing sql queries but they work....